# Location detection and HTTP call on background mode using cordova-plugin-background-mode

Tags: cordova, background, geolocation

I have an ionic app in which the app behaves in the following way when it is in the foreground. A service in the app checks geolocation every x seconds using navigator.geolocation and based on the coordinates it calls another service to do some http calls. Now these things obviously don't work when the app is in the background, but it is very crucial that my app is able to do these detections and make these calls (Which includes changing some variables in the service.js)

I have the following code in my app.js so far.

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
    // Android customization
    cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.setDefaults({     title:  "XYZ",
    ticker: "XYZ is running on background",
    text:   "XYZ is keeping track now on the background. This is a test message"});
    // Enable background mode
   cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.enable();

cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.onfailure = function(errorCode){
    console.log("failed")
};

// Called when background mode has been activated
cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.onactivate = function () {

      console.log("Hello from background!); // works fine


      ////////////////// This piece of code doesn't execute /////////////
      function success(position){
       console.log("In success function");
       MyService.doStuff(); // This will make some http calls
      }

       function success(position){
       console.log("In success function");
       MyService.doStuff(); // This will make some http calls
      }

       function error(error){
       console.log("In error function");
      }

       var options = {timeout: 60000, enableHighAccuracy: true}; // options for checking geolocation

       navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options); // eventually I'd like to add setInterval to this piece, so it executes every x seconds
      //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

}

cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.ondeactivate = function() {
  console.log("Bye Bye from Background!"); // works fine
};


}, false);
```

If this works I should be able to wrap the piece in a function, and setInterval, so the location gets checked every x seconds. Can anyone suggest how I can make this work on the background. It works fine when I do this on the foreground.

Android: 5.1.1

Comment: Are you using Anroid 6.0? if so, please put that information in your message.

Comment: My Version is Android 5.1.1

Comment: hmm... Okay. I thought you might have a Android 6.0 feature working. But your issue might be something else. I am going to look at your post much closer now. Here is the 6.0 feature that could block your work [Android 6.0 & doze](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/android-doze.md)

Comment: Okay. I read your message again. There is both a background plugin and there is a background service for Geolocation. However you need to consider that your App will stop working with Android 6.0. Do you want an answer?

Comment: Yes Please. Any information I can get is very important to me right now.  Thank You.

Comment: Okay. Last questions so I can give a better answer. **Please add to your post** Is this your first hybrid App? What platform are you developing on? Windows, MacOS? Are you setting the compiler version? (if you don't know, say "don't know") TIA

Comment: Hey Purpamine, have u done this?

Answer (score 1):

@Purpamine,
the good news is you have succeed where many developers stumble.

With Cordova/Phonegap, most anything that needs to be done (on the mobile device) is done in one of three (3) ways:

1. Javascript library
2. Cordova "core" plugin
3. 3rd-party plugin

In your case, you are using the "core" [geolocation library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-geolocation). If you search the [Cordova Plugin repository](http://cordova.apache.org/plugins/) for [geolocation](http://cordova.apache.org/plugins/?q=geolocation) (at this time), you will find 24 plugins. Add the keyword `background` and you are left with [9 plugins](http://cordova.apache.org/plugins/?q=geolocation%20background). Most of these plugins will work with Android and iOS. At this time, there appears to be no *geolocation background* plugins that work for **winphone**. Since I am not working on this task (background), I cannot recommend any plugin at this time.

You should know that many of these plugins are based on the "core" library, so much of the work you have done is still valid.

One last thing, the following is [from a post](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/heads-up-android-6-0-sdk-23-blocks-background-operations) I made months ago (Nov 28, 2015).

### HEADS UP: Android 6.0 SDK-23 blocks background operations.

> As of Android 6.0 SDK-23 (Marshmallow), Google is putting in place new features/barriers that effect background operations. The two (2) are related and are called *DOZE* and *App Suspend*. The point of these new "features" is to save battery life.
>
> In the worst possible scenario, instant messages will be discarded. In another case, your app will be able to use network or background operations *only* once a day. In another case, you can get operations once every 15 minutes. In the best case, you can get exact temporal operations, but things like `JobScheduler` will still fail.
>
> Oh and that `whitelist` list reference I found is to let the end-user add your App to a `whitelist` on the *mobile device*. This means you can ask the end-user to put your app on the whitelist, so you can partially ignore *DOZE* and *App Suspend*.
>
> However, the (google) documentation warns:
>
> > Note: Google Play policies prohibit apps from requesting direct exemption from Power Management features in Android 6.0+ (Doze and App Standby) unless the core function of the app is adversely affected.
>
> I've already done a preliminary on this and I found very few articles, blog posts, or SO threads. (...) In the meantime, I have notes at
>   [Android 6.0 & Doze](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/android-doze.md)
>
> **Android (Official)** [Optimizing for Doze and App Standby](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html)

Comment: Ok. So what I get from this is are you asking me to look into these 3rd-party plugin and utilize them instead of using the core functionality?

Comment: Yes, you should look into 3rd-party plugins. In addition, all manufactures are restricting background operations because they are draining battery life - the #1 complaint by end-users. Needless to say, any decision you make may be fraught with trouble. As such, I also recommend you consider that you may (or may not) need to rewrite your app in 6-18 months - where it is related to battery use. Best of Luck.

Comment: Thank You. App is supposed to be used while driving, so not super concerned about battery, as it can be plugged in while driving.

Comment: I understand. This is yours to deal with. I am just informing you of the situation. Best of Luck